# Lambert W of 2πi

Tags: lambert-w

$$2πi = 2πi, $$

$$2πi = 2πi \cdot e^{2πi}$$
Where $$e^{2πi} =1$$

$$W(2πi) = W(2πi \cdot e^{2πi}),$$
$$W(2πi) = 2πi$$
Where $$ W(xe^x) = x$$

When I check whether the last statement is valid in WolframAlpha, it tellls me that it is not. What have I done wrong?

Comment: Does $W$ even have a clear definition over the complex numbers – is $z \longmapsto ze^z$ a bijection?

Comment: Lambert W is not  a single valued function. See:  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_W_function

Comment: The Lambert W function is multi-valued, its value depend on which branch you pick. On branch $1$ (instead of the default branch $0$?), $W(2\pi i)$  do equal to $2\pi i$. On WA, you can use `LambertW[1,2*Pi*i]` to compute that value.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Could you write this as an answer and also provide a definition of the Lambert W on branch 1?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to Achille Hui.

Apparently the Lambert W function has a seperate branch for the complex numbers. Hence
$W_1(2πi) =2πi $, while $W_0(2πi) \neq2πi $
WolframAlpha shows `LambertW[1,2*Pi*i]`  to be $2πi$.